# How to add button and javascript to Wordpress admin edit list

Tags: wordpress

How to add  button and javascript to Wordpress admin edit list？

This is what I'm looking for:
[image: http://www.flying-design.net/question.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an action to the row you can use the `post_row_actions` filter (or `page_row_actions` for pages). `Place this code in your functions.php` file.

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'my_post_row_actions', 10, 2);
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'my_post_row_actions', 10, 2);
function my_post_row_actions($actions, $post){

    $actions['my_action'] = '<a rel="permalink" class="my-inline-action" title="My Action" href="#">My Action</a>';
    return $actions;

}
```

So this covers the HTML side of things. Obviously in the above you would need to come up with a more meaningful handle that `my_action`, as well as a title. If you are wishing to use some jQuery though, you can leave the href as `#`.

For the jQuery side of things - what exactly do you want to do? Without more information, it's pretty much impossible to help.